# Why bisection width of star connected network is 1?

Tags: parallel-computing

This may seem like a simple question, but I can neither find the answer on the internet nor AI tools can give a proper answer. I was reading a book about static networks and I saw that the bisection width of the star topology is 1, but it didn't make sense to me. The definition of bisection width is given as follows: The number of links that need to be removed to divide a network into two equal subnets. How can removing 1 link divide the network into two equal parts?

In a star-connected network, one processor acts as the central processor. Every other processor has a communication link connecting it to this processor. Communication between any pair of processors is routed through the central processor.

[image]

The book: Introduction to Parallel Computing, Second Edition by Ananth Grama, Anshul Gupta, George Karypis, Vipin Kumar.
Unfortunately, the book does not explain why the bisection width of the star topology is 1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the correct answer is floor(N/2). But that's just my word against the book's.